# Google Foobar- Code works in my IDE but not in foobar. Static method?

Tags: python, testing, case

I am  doing one of the Google foobar challenges and my code returns the right values in my IDE, but not in foobar. I'm new to python and think I'm missing something on how foobar reads the code or calls the function. Help is much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
def solution(area):
    totalarea=int(area)
    sq1calc=abs(totalarea ** 0.5)
    sq1 = int(sq1calc)
    sq1area = sq1 ** 2
    sq2calc=abs((totalarea - sq1area) ** 0.5)
    sq2 = int(sq2calc)
    sq2area = sq2 ** 2
    sq3calc=abs((totalarea - sq1area - sq2area) ** 0.5)
    sq3 = int(sq3calc)
    sq3area = sq3 ** 2
    sq4calc=abs((totalarea - sq1area - sq2area - sq3area) ** 0.5)
    sq4 = int(sq4calc)
    sq4area = sq4 ** 2
    print(sq1area,sq2area,sq3area,sq4area, sep=",")
solution()
```

Two test case input/outputs are provided and my code runs these fine in my IDE.

Test cases:
Input:
solution.solution(15324)
Output:
15129,169,25,1

Input:
solution.solution(12)
Output:
9,1,1,1

I've read that foobar used the 'static method' but I'm not quite sure what that means or how it applies.
No error information is provided by foobar.
I should at least be getting the test cases right...

If I enter this into foobar, it says Test 2 passes:

```
def solution(area):
   print ("""9,1,1,1""")
```

Comment: Can you please provide the real code? The code given would have indentation errors and not provide the output you've specified.

Comment: I updated the code in my post - sorry about that. I copied in an older version. I also added an example that foobar does accept. My code calculations provide the same answer, but foobar doesn't accept it. What am I doing wrong?